# SharePoint 2010 Site accessible without permission

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am able to access SharePoint site and Library without any permission.
When I check my permission it is showing that "None" permission to me.
Its really strange !!! Does anyone has any clue on this.

Note : Anonymous User access is not there!!

Comment: may be it can be admin account

Comment: Check your SharePoint group having any permission

Comment: Yes I checked in the Group.. There is nothing. 
If it is Admin account then all the permission should be visible right Hardik?

Answer (score 0):

Access can be granted through [web application policies in central administration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608071(v=office.14).aspx).